# When to use in references to instead of in reference to?

Tags: american-english

A couple of times, I've come across the express `in reference to` and `in references to`. What triggers the need to use of `in references to` instead of `in reference to`?

EDIT: Below is the message where I found this expression:

> An interesting use of the possessive is in references to the name of firms.

**NOTE: I'm a native French speaker, trying to learn english, so I apologize in advance if this question has an obvious answer.**

Comment: Please note that ELL is tailored more to less advanced questions. // Many nouns have both non-count (I love drinking coffee) and count (I'd like three coffees, please) usages. Here, 'in references to' is a count usage (reference 1, reference 2 ...-- whether or not they are officially listed as 'references') (think 'in the various references ...')  whereas 'in reference to' is a non-count usage (in fact, a fixed phrase – in this case, arguably a compound preposition, meaning 'referring to' / 'concerning').  Fixed phrases like this usually have the non-count (and singular in form) variant.

Comment: _In reference to_ is an idiomatic phrase meaning _concerning_ or _about_. If you pluralize _references_ it's not an idiom any more, but just part of a phrase like _in references to Hitler, there are often disagreements_.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Helpful!

Comment: We would need to see the context of your quotes in order to tell whether they were idiomatic usages or not.

Comment: I have updated my question. Thanks

Comment: In the quoted context "references" is correct, since there are likely an untold number of them.  I would have pluralized "name", though, or said "... in references to the name of a firm".